# Card reader in MSI x370 don't work

Tags: 12.04, card-reader

Card reader in MSI x370 don't work.
Ubuntu 12.04 64bit
gnomeShell

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 14h Processor Root Complex
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Wrestler [Radeon HD 6320]
00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Wrestler HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6250/6310]
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 40)
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SBx00 SMBus Controller (rev 42)
00:14.1 IDE interface: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 IDE Controller (rev 40)
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA) (rev 40)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 LPC host controller (rev 40)
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge (rev 40)
00:15.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB700/SB800/SB900 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 0)
00:15.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB900 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 2)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 0 (rev 43)
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 6
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 5
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 7
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 06)
```

lsusb

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 5986:030c Acer, Inc 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Wireless Mouse M305
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0139 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
```

Comment: Please provide more information. You can start with running `lspci` and `lsusb` in console and copy the results here.

Comment: copypasted in question

Answer (score 0):

***(this is not a response, just a long comment)***

Okay, the good news is that you see that the USB device is already recognized: `0bda:0139 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.`, but the bad news is that now you need to look at the kernel logs to see what happens when you put a card in the reader.

Here are the steps:

1. Open a terminal and run `sudo -i` to get login as *root*;
2. Run `tail -n0 -f /var/log/dmesg` (as root);
3. Put a card in the reader, and wait a few seconds. You should get a few lines of log printed on the screen.
4. Copy those lines here (again in the question body) to see if we can get anything from it.

Comment: I have a probleme with this: this comand don't show anything, it just blinking, after inserting card the same.

Comment: Okay, not seeing anything there kind of confirms that the device is not recognized as a USB Mass Storage. You can try the methods mentioned on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DebuggingUSBStorage to see if you can find any clue of what's going wrong.

Comment: Anyway, I think I wouldn't be able to help any more, as I don't have access to a similar hardware. But you can update your question with more detail and someone else might be able to help you. :)